# createMaterialTopTabNavigator how to add swipe listner so i can call a function on swipe

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here i am using

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
```

I want to listen swipe when i change the tab by swipping the tab
so i can handle a function which will determine current Tab screen name.
I cannot found any Event listner for this purpose.
Please Help

```
function swipeListner(tabName){
  setCurrentTab(tabName)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

createMaterialTopTabNavigator doesn't provide the onSwipe prop, try out other top tab components.